# Centering variables in regression leads to the same model of original variables, why still doing that?

Tags: regression, interaction, multicollinearity, polynomial, centering

The regression model
y= b0+ b1 x + b2 x^2 + b3 x^3

and the second regression model
y = b0 +b1 (x-u) + b2 (x-u)^2 + b3 (x-u)^3
where u is the mean of x

These two models lead to the same curves, or says the same fitted values. I understand centering the variables for polynomial or interaction regressors will lower the correlations of regressors and therefore reduce the multicolinearity, variance inflation, prediction interval... But they are still the same model, does the difference between the variances of two identical models really mean something important?

R code example:

```
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- runif(100)
u <- mean(x)

model1<- lm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3))
model2 <- lm(y~x+I((x-u)^2)+I((x-u)^3))

summary(model1)
summary(model2)
```

They have the same sd error, R squared.... Their fitted values are the same as well.

Comment: Are the standard errors the same? Can you paste in the actual code & output?

Comment: Yes they are the same

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, you'll get exactly the same fitted values with centered explanatory variables as with the original variables.  In addition, because model building with polynomials is usually done by eliminating the highest order term, then rerunning the model, then checking the remaining highest order term, etc. (backward elimination), you'll even end up with the same models.  The reason for centering is to decrease multicollinearity, which can grow large enough with some data sets (with higher degree polynomials) that $X'X$ might not be easily invertible and you get computational errors.

When you have polynomials in different explanatory variables (i.e. y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + I(x2^2)), having lower multicollinearity is handy, because it makes model selection work better.  It's the multiple explanatory variable case where centering really pays off.